# How to review late answer?

Tags: discussion, review

How to review late answer?

I saw some people that have the steward badge on late answers. How is it possible?

Always that I want to review late answers there are none. I wait for a short time and refresh it a lot but still there are none. How can I review more  late answers?

Comment: Spend a _lot_ of time refreshing in the review queue. Or just take what comes, if there are late answers, fine, if not, also fine.

Comment: Indeed "some people" have earned the Steward Badge for Late Answers reviews, but only three people have this (out of $343$ Steward Badges total).  The first to get the Steward Badge for Late Answers was Amzoti in Jan. 2014.  The next two were in Dec. 2015 and Jan. 2016, almost a two year gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is nothing special about these reviews; it is just that they are more rare and thus not that often available (plus the scarcity creates additional demand).

As said in a comment if you want to perform those reviews frequently you need to check often, or have a script that does it for you.

For example https://stackapps.com/questions/6517/review-queue-desktop-notification-script could help.

It is not for late answers specifically though.

In addition, at some point  there was a flood of such reviews as the criteria were changed. But due to daily limits this did not contribute that much on an individual basis.

Comment: So nice app it will helpful.

Comment: I am glad you find it helpful. But please never forget to keep the priorities right. quality trumps quantity.

Comment: The system will test it sometimes I can't make wrong reviwes it gives a deleted answer and want to reviwe it then if you don't do anything you will baned from reviwing.